# How to get a binded key not to type into Entry box

Tags: python, python-3.x, tkinter, diacritics, tkinter-entry

I have a program in which I want to type in, for example, ĝ when g^ is typed in an Entry box. *I have got the ĝ to appear*, but seem unable to rid the entry box of the ^ that has been typed in (yes, I have tried to use the delete function). As far as I can work out, the ^ isn't typed out until after the binded functions have occurred, meaning that if I try and index `"^"` or `"/"`, it hasn't actually been typed out yet.

```
from tkinter import *
tk = Tk()
entry = Entry(tk)
entry.pack()
entry.bind("^", lambda x: accent(entry, "^"))
entry.bind("/", lambda x: accent(entry, "/"))

def accent(object, accent):
    global entry
    letter = entry.get()[len(entry.get())-1]
    entry.delete((len(entry.get())-1), len(entry.get()))
    if accent == "^":
        if letter == "a":
            entry.insert(END, "â")
        if letter == "g":
            entry.insert(END, "ĝ")
    if accent == "/":
        if letter == "a":
            entry.insert(END, "á")
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your binding needs to return `"break"`, which tells tkinter to stop any further processing of the event. Returning "break" will prevent the character from being inserted.

Comment: Doesn’t that also stop future binds of the same character? Can’t that also be an issue?

Comment: Is there a way to stop the character from inserting but letting future binds  go through?